# Push/Fetch OpenSSL SSL_connect: SYSCALL

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab

I tried to push my existing repo yesterday and today and faced the same issue:

```
alisafarpour@Alis-Air rouyesh-ehsan-react % git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/taylor.ren/test.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.com:443
```

I tried to fetch/push from GitLab UI and that works fine.

Can anyone help in this situation?

I am using MacBook air m1

Comment: `H:\temp\gitlabtest` … "MacBook air m1" … Hmm, really?

Comment: I fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution I'm behind a proxy and it makes an issue and I must add proxy config in `.gitconfig` after adding my proxy config in `.gitconfig` my problem is fixed, this code work for me :

```
[http]
    proxy = socks5://your.proxy.server:4080
[https]
    proxy = socks5://your.proxy.server:4080
```